# sintaxis error php calculadora

Tags: php

Tengo dos archivos.

Código de calculadora.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculadora Simple</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculadora Simple</h1>

        //creamos el selector de operaciones

       <form action="resultado.php" method="post">
           <select name="operador">
               <option value="suma">Suma</option>
               <option value="resta">Resta</option>
               <option value="multiplicacion">Multiplicacion</option>
               <option value="division">Division</option>
           </select><br/>

           // Introducimos primer numero

           <input type="text" name="valor1"><br />

           // Introducimos segundor numero

           <input type="text" name="valor2"><br />

           // Borrar los valores

           <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

           // Recoger los datos

           <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

y en este último me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de **resultado.php:**

```
<?php>

    if($_POST["valor1"] !="" && $_POST["valor2"] !=""){

        if($_POST["operador"] =="suma"){

            print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] + $_POST["valor2"]);

            print ('<br /><a href="calculadora.php">Volver</a> ');

        }elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "resta") {

           print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] - $_POST["valor2"]);

           print ('<br /><a href="calculadora.php">Volver</a> ');

        }elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "multiplcacion") {

           print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] * $_POST["valor2"]);

           print ('<br /><a href="calculadora.php">Volver</a> ');

       }elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "division") {

           print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] / $_POST["valor2"]);

           print ('<br /><a href="calculadora.php">Volver</a> ');

       }

   }else {

      print ("Introduzca un numero valido");

      print ('<br /><a href="calculadora.php">Volver</a>') ;

  }

?>
```

Esta es la pantalla que me muestra el segundo archivo:

```
var_dump('Resultado 1: ' . $_POST["valor1"] . ' Resultado 2: ' . $_POST["valor2"]); if(($_POST["valor1"] !="") && ($_POST["valor2"] !="")){ if($_POST["operador"] =="suma"){ print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] + $_POST["valor2"]); print ('
Volver '); } elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "resta") { print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] - $_POST["valor2"]); print ('
Volver '); } elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "multiplcacion") { print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] * $_POST["valor2"]); print ('
Volver '); } elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "division") { print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] / $_POST["valor2"]); print ('
Volver '); } } else { print ("Introduzca un numero valido"); print ('
Volver') ; } ?>
```

Comment: if($_POST["valor1"] !="" && $_POST["valor2"] !=""){ sustituyo el and por && pero me sigue dando fallo, el mismo fallo que antes

Comment: prueba con `if(($_POST["valor1"] !="") && ($_POST["valor2"] !=""))`

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo fallo, no se que puede ocurrir

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer un **var_dump()** a $_POST["valor1"] y a $_POST["valor2"] antes de meterte en el primer **if** a lo mejor no estás recuperando el valor que esperas.

Comment: El error se quita pero obtengo la pantalla de resultado. php igual, con todo el codigo

Comment: Antes de **if($_POST["valor1"] !="" && $_POST["valor2"] !=""){** inserta **var_dump('Valor 1: ' . $_POST["valor1"] . ' Valor 2: ' . $_POST["valor2"]);** Eso te devolverá lo que contienen exactamente y así podremos comprobar lo que te está llegando por post.

Comment: he probado con esto, gracias por compartirlo, pero el resultado de resultado.php, es mostrarme todo el código

Comment: Se refiere a que var_dump nos va ayudar a encontrar el error, no que lo vaya a solucionar. Sube el resultado que da el var_dump

Comment: **var_dump()** imprime por pantalla el contenido de una variable, incluso si se trata de un array. Lo que quiero es lo que acaba de decirte el compañero @Mikel Ferreiro XD

Comment: actualizado en el post principal

Comment: @kit creo no has entendido, el objetivo del var_dump, es que al ejecutar el código se muestre en pantalla el contenido de las variables $_POST["valor1"] y $_POST["valor2"] para poder comprobar que llega lo que esperas. Ejecuta el códido y copia lo que imprima en pantalla, luego subelo aquí.

Comment: var_dump('Resultado 1: ' . $_POST["valor1"] . ' Resultado 2: ' . $_POST["valor2"]); if(($_POST["valor1"] !="") && ($_POST["valor2"] !="")){ if($_POST["operador"] =="suma"){ print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] + $_POST["valor2"]); print ('
Volver '); } elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "resta") { print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] - $_POST["valor2"]); print ('
Volver '); } elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "multiplcacion") { print ($resultado = $_POST["valor1"] * $_POST["valor2"]); print ('
Volver '); } elseif ($_POST["operador"] ==. No me deja copiar todo el texto por pantalla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas iniciando lenguaje php con `<?php>`

Debes hacerlo correctamente con `<?php`

Para escribir en **PHP** o **embeber** en html debes abrir y cerrar con `<?php ?>` o `<? ?>` en caso de tener habilitado las short tags en tu archivo de configuración de PHP.

> php.ini

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Comment: ese es el problema, gracias!! mil gracias!!

Comment: dios mio ni lo había visto. Que buena XD

Comment: Bien visto. Claro, al no interpretar el **PHP** le estaba mostrando al OP el código como si fuese un string literal. Vaya tela.